# Not getting accessibility events in redmi device in android

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, system

I am creating a app which detect the system level event which work successfully on Google pixel, Samsung, OnePlus, oppo, vivo, realme devices.

when I enable accessibility service from setting then the **onServiceConnected** method called, and in which I created a object on **`accessibiltyServiceInfo()`** class, and attached the some event. and the events getting successfully when that particular system event occur.

But the redmi (Xiaomi)devices , after **onServiceConnected** called, the **`accessibiltyServiceInfo()`** class's object not created , and getting null so I am not able to attach the event on that accessibility service, so no event capturing,

.

**Note my Application have :-**

- All system level permission
- all required permission
- many background service and broadcast
- administrator access

.
**Code Snippet :-**

```
 override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        val info = AccessibilityServiceInfo()
       
            Log.d("info_service_status", ":${info}")
            info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.CONTENTS_FILE_DESCRIPTOR
            info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.CONTENT_CHANGE_TYPE_STATE_DESCRIPTION
            info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_GESTURE_DETECTION_START
            info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_GESTURE_DETECTION_END
            info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_LONG_CLICKED


            serviceInfo = info
        }
```

Comment: Finally resolved my issue, for this I added Xiaomi related permissions and tags.

Comment: Can you share the code I am facing same issue